# What best tool to find files with content?

Tags: microsoft-windows, find

Windows 10, Emacs 26.1.

I need to find all files that content specific text ,e,g. ("hello").
I need to specify:

1. is case sensitive
2. is search also in all subfolders
3. to find by some text and by regexp
4. The result must show in separate buffer (e.g. Result)
5. does not depend on the external grep tool

I know about **grep** tool. But it not very comfortable.

Comment: did you try ack? https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Ack

Comment: also there are some specific-windows functions in the bottom of the grep page here: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrepMode

Comment: If you have a Unix-like `find` and `grep` installed and visible to Emacs (and in general it's very sensible to do so), then you can just use `M-x rgrep`

Comment: To be clear, the **best** tool to find files with content matching some pattern will categorically require an external program.  That needn't necessarily be `grep` -- there are alternatives (`ripgrep` is well-regarded) -- but having `grep` installed is *highly* recommended, even if you also install alternatives.  Any solution which does not rely on an external tool will not be the **best** possible tool for the job.

Comment: The question is too broad and unclear. There are many, many ways to do what you ask. You need to specify what you want, not just say that you don't want `grep`. Your question might be more appropriate for a discussion site such as Reddit.

Comment: "More comfortable" isn't a precise description. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I found external package for find/replace files by content and extensions in folder and subfolders - "xah-find" - http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp-xah-find-text.html  . It's not depend from external tool like grep/find. It's create on pure Elisp.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [elgrep](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep/master/elgrep.el).
The github version linked here already has already an option for case sensitivity.
Within a day or so that version should also be available via [`list-packages`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Menu.html#Package-Menu) from [melpa](https://melpa.org/).

Some features:

- Menu for specifying search strings and search options with history and <kbd>M-tab</kbd> completion.
- `elgrep` does **not** depend on the external `grep` tool
- asynchronous recursive search (optionally with limits for the search depth)
- Specify directories and files to be searched by regular expressions.
- Choose how many context lines around matches are shown.
- Extra results buffer as for `find-grep`.
- Editable results buffer. It is possible to write the edited results back to the matching files.
- `.pdf`-files are also searched for matches with the help of the external tool `pdftotext`. (Make sure that `pdftotext` is in the `PATH` if you want to use that feature.)
- The search function can be specified. You can replace `re-search-forward` by `search-forward` to search for text instead of regular expressions.

Screenshot of the menu:

[image: elgrep-menu]